# in Pandas, how can print() and display() render completely different numbers?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, ipython

I have a dataframe, imported from a CSV.  One of the columns is `1` or `null` (NaN).

- When I view it with `print`, it shows as a `1`.
- When I view it with `display` it renders as a `0.0`

When I evaluate it, with an operator like `>` it acts as a `1`.

Why is this?  How can I make sure `display` doesn't confuse me?

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example CSV file that replicates the problem.  Also, note that `display()` is an IPython thing, not a Python thing, so I'll add that tag for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem anymore, after running `jupyter lab build` after installing a new `nbextension`